# Getting constant Unreal crashes when porting a blender model to it

Tags: mesh, export, blend-files, .fbx, unreal-engine

I keep getting the error:

LoginId:1978d23c4c338d46283e3c999ce73661
EpicAccountId:4036e797f1d047eba2e8cc9c84c55e1e

Assertion failed: (Index >= 0) & (Index < ArrayNum) [File:D:\Build++UE4\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers/Array.h] [Line: 614] Array index out of bounds: 0 from an array of size 0

UE4Editor_Core
UE4Editor_Core
UE4Editor_MeshBuilder
UE4Editor_MeshBuilder
UE4Editor_MeshBuilder
UE4Editor_MeshBuilder
UE4Editor_UnrealEd
UE4Editor_UnrealEd
UE4Editor_UnrealEd
UE4Editor_AssetTools
UE4Editor_AssetTools
UE4Editor_UnrealEd
UE4Editor_UnrealEd
UE4Editor_Engine
UE4Editor_Engine
UE4Editor_UnrealEd
UE4Editor_UnrealEd
UE4Editor
UE4Editor
UE4Editor
UE4Editor
UE4Editor
kernel32
ntdll

every time i try to port my skeletal mesh to it. I've messed with the smoothing groups, the UVs, and some of the import options in Unreal to no avail. Any ideas?

Blender Export Settings:

[image]

Unreal Import Settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it appears that unreal engine crashes when the blender animation FBX is without a material.

This means if you add a texture or material to your object it will work.